# slidedown of a new textbox by hovering over a text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that when I mousehover on a particular text a new textbox should slidedown from it containing some checkboxes.

Comment: Do you want checkboxes with a textbox?

Comment: the checkboxes could be in a new window that slidesdown.

Answer (score 1):

```
<span onMouseEnter="showDiv()" onMouseLeave="HideDiv()">My text</span>
<input type="text" id="container" style="display:none"><input type="checkbox"/></div>

<script>
    function showDiv()
    {
        $("#container").show();
    }

    function hideDiv()
    {
        $("#container").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: good answer but he asked "a new textbox should slidedown from it containing some checkboxes". so edit <div id="container" style="display:none">**<input type="text" style="width:200px"/>**<input type="checkbox"/></div>

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';">My text</div>
 <div id="div1"><input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"/>Mycheckbox</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1
    { display:none; }
```

Please see the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/mrEC5/

Please find the updated code below .

HTML

```
    <ul class="link">
    <li>
        <label id="1" class="check"><input  type="checkbox" /> Checkbox One</label>

        <ul  id="checkbox-container1" class="hidden">
            <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox One</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox Two</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox Three</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label id="2" class="check"><input  type="checkbox" /> Checkbox One</label>

        <ul  id="checkbox-container2" class="hidden">
            <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox </label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox </label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Checkbox </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
ul li{list-style:none;}
```

Script:

```
$(function(){ 
    // shows checkboxes on mouseover and hides them on mouseout
    $( "ul.link li .check" ).hover(       
        function(e) {
            var id1=this.id;             
            $("#"+id1).closest('ul').find('#checkbox-container'+id1).slideDown();          
        }, function(e) {
            var id2=this.id;          
            $(this).closest('ul').find('#checkbox-container'+id2).slideUp();           
        }
    );
});
```

Find the working fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/UQE2F/7/

Comment: thanks :) it works but i want that it should open like a new window is sliding from the text. please help!! i m really stuck over here

Comment: @user1532663 : I ll be glad to help. can you clearly explain?. am not able to get your requirement

Comment: Actually I have a table with three columns and 7 rows. Each column has a checkbox with some text. Now I want that when I go over any checkbox or its text a new window should slide down containing some more text such as checkboxes which user can select. Also this window should be closed as I go over another checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one with HTML, CSS and Javascript separated and animation while showing and hiding.

Check the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/UQE2F/1/

```
Hope this helps.
```

Comment: thanks!! but i want that dropdown to stay till i dont go on another text which will also have a similar dropdown

Comment: Hi, as per your requirement I've made some changes, check the updated jsfiddle example -------- [link](http://jsfiddle.net/UQE2F/3/) http://jsfiddle.net/UQE2F/3/

Comment: Hi!! I tried the code.Its working in the fiddle but not in my code. can u plz help again. I am attaching the same code which I saved as html but still its not working.

Comment: The code uses jQuery, hence it should work. Check if your page has jquery. If it is not there, append following line in <body> tag.  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>